# How to connect ms-access database with android app..?

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android. I want to develop an android app which retrieve data from Ms-Access DB online. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to provide some sort of an interface to the DB you want to access. It can be some sort of REST service or a plain web service that will let you perform the desired operations.

Then, when you have the service up and running, you should create an Android app that consumes the service, using HTTP requests.

To transfer the data between the service and the application, you will need to use some sort of a data transfer format. The most popular and easy to use at the moment is JSON.

The task you are describing is not easy, as you need to research a lot of technologies and standards and later implement them.

For the service part you can use some of the popular server - side languages and technologies available - Java, Ruby, php, etc.